# GLSL: What version is used when no version is specified?

Tags: opengl, glsl

When there is no version specified in the first line of a GLSL shader (so nothing like "#version 330", which version is actually used?

Is it vendor (or even driver) specific?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*What is the default GLSL version?*

- Assume the default version is 1.10
- Note that the `#version` directive always must be on the first line

> The `#version` directive must appear before anything else in a shader, save for whitespace and comments. If a `#version` directive does not appear at the top, then it assumes 1.10, which is almost certainly not what you want.
>
> – [OpenGL Wiki](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Core_Language_(GLSL)#Version)

If it's in relation to combining sources, then you could leave out the `#version` directive and do something like this:

```
const GLsizei stringCount = 2;
const GLchar *strings[stringCount] = {
    "#version 330 core\n",
    shaderSource,
};

glShaderSource(shader, stringCount, strings, NULL);
```